# Ember ErrorRoute: model is null when throwing string

Tags: ember.js

I have an error route and controller defined in my Ember app and it generally works, but if some code throws a simple string, e.g. `throw 'invalid argument'`, the model property on my error controller is always null.

I've created a JSBin [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/degag/2/edit) illustrating the problem.

Can anyone explain why throwing an object allows the model to be set but throwing a primitive like string does not? How can I capture the error context if I can't control the code that throws exceptions?

Additionally, it seems if I `throw new Error('message')` or `throw new Ember.Error('message')` the error is logged to the console but never triggers the error route transition. Is this intended?

Comment: I can't answer this particular question, but I can say that you should probably be throwing errors from the `model` hook, not the `setupController` hook. The [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) explicitly says that errors thrown from `model` are handled in the `error` handler, but it doesn't say that about `setupController`.

Comment: The dummy code used setupController because the model hook would not be called when passing a model in a link-to helper. I understand your point but don't think it's relevant to the question.